# Display featured image on blog page

Tags: post-thumbnails

The commented out portion is what I've added to pull the featured image set on the blog page. Without that chunk I'm able to set the image, or pull from the home page's featured image if that page/post doesn't have one. But once I enable the section for 'page_for_posts' everything else goes haywire and it starts outputting an image that isn't set as the feature for anything.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $imageInfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
    $imageUrl = $imageInfo[0];
}
//if ( get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
//      $imageInfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ), 'full' ) ); 
//      $imageUrl = $imageInfo[0];
//}
if ( !has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $imageInfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( '46' ), 'full' );
    $imageUrl = $imageInfo[0];
}

$cssoutput = ".site-header { background-image: url('" . $imageUrl . "'); } \n";

echo 
"<style type=\"text/css\">" . $cssoutput . "</style>";
```

Comment: What does `get_option( 'page_for_posts')` return? And why use `if` and no `else if`?

Comment: It doesn't return anything anticipated, instead the output on all pages (except those WITH a featured image) is an image not used on any post or page. It *should* return the featured image of the page designated as the blog page. 

Originally was using else if before I needed to target the page_for_posts, not sure the best approach to making it happen.

Comment: You didn't answered my question, what does the `get_option('page_for_posts');` returns when you vardump this?

Comment: Does the same, it doesn't return any expected results.

Comment: Can you post the result please?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? Struggling to solve this.